# C++ Range Error at Memory Location?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, location, range

Newbie here. I seem to get Range Error at memory location when trying to run this short programme. I have no idea what it means and it is getting a little frustrating.

```
int main()
{
int grains_current = 1;
vector <int> previous;
int sum = 0;
int i = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<10; ++i) sum += previous[i];
    previous.push_back(grains_current);

    grains_current = grains_current*2;

    if (sum >= 10)
        cout<<i<<"\t\n\n";
```

Comment: Your indentation suggests that you intend for all the lines after the `for` to be within the loop, but that isn't the case. They would have to be within braces for that to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum += previous[i];
```

At this point, the vector `previous` hasn't been given any values, so you're getting Undefined Behavior for accessing this address out of range.

Update: Here is what I think your code should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    previous.push_back(grains_current);
    sum += previous[i];

    grains_current *= 2;

    if (grains_current >= 1000)
        std::cout << sum << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: The question is: the chess inventor was being rewarded for creating the game ...the inventor asked for one grain of rice for the first square, 2 for the second, 4 for the third and so on. Write a programme to calculate how many squares are required to give the inventor at least 1000 grains of rice.

Comment: @RavenEye See the updated code. Tell me if it works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks, that works great and I can see where I was going wrong. I just need to find the amount of squares it requires to have 1000 grains but just printing out the loop number (i) should do it, right?

Comment: @RavenEye Yes. You should print out `i` then `break;`